# gradle uploadArchives Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact in remote

Tags: android, maven

I want to publish my **library module** in Android Studio, here is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url:"http://xxx.git") {
                authentication(userName: "xxx", password: "xxx")
            }
            pom.groupId = 'com.abc.mylib'
            pom.artifactId = 'mylib'
            pom.version = '1.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run gradle task *uploadArchives*, the console print these messages:

```
Could not find artifact com.abc.mylib:mylib:pom:1.0.0 in remote (http://xxx.git)
Could not find artifact com.abc.mylib:mylib:aar:1.0.0 in remote (http://xxx.git)
:mylib:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mylib:uploadArchives'.

  > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
  >   Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact com.abc.mylib:mylib:aar:1.0.0 in remote (http://xxx.git)

I also edited the "http://xxx.git" to "http://xxx/raw/master", not working either.

please help...

Comment: Hey. Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: @Dittimon Jun ,yes I've handled this. What's your problem now?

Comment: how to fix the problem

Comment: Please share how you've handled this.

Comment: @msa plz see my answer below, hope this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem.

- PART 1: upload archive

Edit your library_module build.gradle like this (store your authentication information in local.properties):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven' // this is a must

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

def artifactGroupId = "com.your.groupid"
def artifactVersion = "0.1.0" // consider add -SNAPSHOT suffix for development branch
def artifactId = "yourmagic"

Properties properties = new Properties()
InputStream inputStream = 
project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream();
properties.load(inputStream)

def YOUR_ACCOUNT = properties.getProperty('YOUR_ACCOUNT')
def YOUR_PASSWORD = properties.getProperty('YOUR_PASSWORD')

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "your maven url") {
            authentication(userName: YOUR_ACCOUNT, password: YOUR_PASSWORD)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "your maven url") {
            authentication(userName: YOUR_ACCOUNT, password: YOUR_PASSWORD)
        }

        pom.groupId = artifactGroupId
        pom.artifactId = artifactId
        pom.version = artifactVersion
    }
}
```

After that, you can execute the task uploadArchives.

[image: execute uploadArchives]

- PART 2: implement your maven dependencies in gradle

In your root build.gradle, add your maven repository url, like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url 'your maven url'
        }
    }
}
```

In your app_module build.gradle, add your magic dependencies,

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.your.groupid:yourmagic:0.1.0' // snapshot version 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
}
```

Hope this will help.